# Conditional Probability based on independence.

Tags: probability

John is distributing free samples of his company's new product to his neighbors. He visits each house on the block to distribute. For simplicity, assume that only one person lives in each house. When he visits a house, he gives the cookie if the occupant is present and is an adult. Independently for each house, the probability that the occupant is present is 3/4 and the probability that the occupant is an adult is 2/3. Find the following:

a) The probability that he gives the first free sample to the third house he visits.

b) The conditional probability that he gives the 5th free sample to the 11th house he visits given that he has already given 4 to the first 8 houses he visited.

c) The probability that he gives out the 2nd free sample to the 5th house he visits.

d) The conditional probability that he gives the 2nd free sample to the 5th house he visits given that the 2nd free sample was not delivered to the 2nd house he visited.

e) The probability that he visits at least 5 houses before he runs out of free samples, assuming that he started with 2 free samples.

My attempt:

a) Probability of success: $p$ =  $\frac34 * \frac23 = \frac12$

Probability of the first sample to third house = $(1-p)^2 * p = \frac18$

b) I think that the condition that he has given out 4 samples to the first 8 houses should not have an effect on the 5th sample since that event has already happened. So this should simply be considering only houses 9,10,11 : $(1-p)^2 * p = \frac18$

c) The only he gives out 2nd sample to the 5th house is that he gives the first sample to one of the first four houses and the 2nd one to the 5th house.

Probability of giving the first sample to one of the first four houses: ${4 \choose 1} * (\frac12)^3 * (\frac12) = \frac14$

Probability 2nd to 5th house: $\frac14 *\frac12 = \frac18$

d) This should be equivalent to saying that he gave the 1st sample to the 1st house and the 2nd to the 5th house.

The probability for that would be: $\frac12 *(\frac12)^3 * \frac12= \frac1{32}$

e)  P(at least 5) = 1 - P(fewer than 5) = 1 - P(1st in one of first 3 houses and 2nd in 4th house)

$ 1 -  ({3 \choose 1} * (\frac12)^2 * (\frac12) * \frac12  ) = \frac{13}{16} $